# Counting in Excel until a special integer comes up

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function

I am trying to get column C to say what column D says (I have typed the value in column D). The problem I am having is that I can not find a way to tell Excel to stop counting when it comes across the next `0`. How can I do this?

[image: Table]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Copy this formula on cell **C2**:

```
=IF(A2<>"",IF(A2=A1,C1+1,1),"")
```

Then copy and paste (dragging) for the rest of the cells on the column.

Comment: You do not really need the first If statement do you? (It works without it)

Comment: @user38498 First `if` checks the cell on column A. If you make a mistake and copy the formula where A is empty it will show nothing, otherwise it will show a value.